# Simplify this javascript for Show one, Hide Rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a script for a gallery in which clicking on an element in the navigation shows only one div, but hides the others.

Currently my script is very specific, as I need to add a new function for every possible instance. See below... You can imagine this grows out of control easily the more images are added.

Can someone help me make this code more generic and elegant? I'm not very experienced with Javascript/JQuery but this is getting a bit embarrassing lol

So in case it's not clear from the code: the #li1, #li2, #li3 etc are the navigational thumbnails which are always visible. The #img1, #img2, #img3 etc. are the variable displayed divs. When one is visible, the rest should be hidden.

Additional questions:

- for every #img1 displayed, I'd like to also show a title in a separate div, let's say #title1, #title2, etc. How do I do this? So eg clicking #li1 would show #img1 and #title1 but hide all other #img.. and #title..
- all #'s contain images. I've noticed that when one of the images is broken, the whole script stops working properly (all #img.. divs show at once). Why is that?
- this script doesn't actually hide all the images until everything is loaded, which you don't notice when running the HTML locally, but you do when you're waiting for the images to download. I'm suspecting because the $("#li1").load(function() refers to a div that is further down in the document. How can I counter this?

I hope I'm not asking too much, I've tried to understand this myself but I can't figure it out.

```js
$("#li1").load(function() {
   $("#img2, #img3, #img4, #img5, #img6, #img7, #img8, #img9, #img10, #img0, #intro").hide();
   $("#img1").show();
});
$("#li1").on('click', function() {
   $("#img2, #img3, #img4, #img5, #img6, #img7, #img8, #img9, #img10, #img0").hide();
   $("#img1").show();
});
$("#li2").on('click', function() {
   $("#img1, #img3, #img4, #img5, #img6, #img7, #img8, #img9, #img10, #img0").hide();
   $("#img2").show();
});
$("#li3").on('click', function() {
   $("#img2, #img1, #img4, #img5, #img6, #img7, #img8, #img9, #img10, #img0").hide();
   $("#img3").show();
});

etc.
```

Comment: You should post this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would add a common class to all of the items. With one call you can hide all and then show the 1

Comment: Can you show some HTML sample just to see what are those `#li` and some parent elements?

Comment: Your code snippet is useless without the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably try something like this:

Thumbnails like:

```
<li class="thumbnail" data-imageId="0">
  ...thumbnail...
</li>
<li class="thumbnail" data-imageId="1">
  ...thumbnail...
</li>
<li class="thumbnail" data-imageId="2">
  ...thumbnail...
</li>
```

Images like:

```
<div class="image" data-imageId="0">
  ...image...
</div>
<div class="image" data-imageId="1" style="display: none;">
  ...image...
</div>
<div class="image" data-imageId="2" style="display: none;">
  ...image...
</div>
<!-- The style attribute in these element hides the element by default,
     while still allowing jQuery to show them using show(). -->
```

And then the JS:

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
   // Hides all images.
   $(".image").hide();

   // Shows appropriate one.
   var imageId = $(this).data("imageId"); // Fetches the value of the data-imageId attribute.
   $(".image[data-imageId="+imageId+"]").show();
});
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! So if I wanted to show a second div for each image (containing the title), would that be possible by just giving this div the same class and data-imageId as the accompanying photo?

Comment: Actually, yes, that's one way. Another way is to make the .image element the root of the entire "package" of stuff you want want to display for each image. It will depend on the structure of your HTML what solution is best. :-)

Comment: why not use `$(this).data("imageId")`?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Good suggestion, thank you. I actually forgot about that one and when I was writing my answer the jQuery API was offline, so I couldn't consult it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have two solutions for you:

**First option:** Edit the HTML code to fix this logic:

```
<li class="nav" data-image="0">0</li>
<li class="nav" data-image="1">2</li>
<li class="nav" data-image="2">3</li>
...
```

...and so on.

Now the JavaScript code will be pretty short and easy, here it is:

```
function showOne(e) {
    var max = 5, // assuming that there are 5 images, from #img0 to #img4
        toShow = e.target.dataset.image;

    for (var i=0; i < max; i++) {
        if (i == toShow) $('#img'+i).hide();
        else $('#img'+i).show();
    }
}

$('.nav').bind('click', showOne);
```

If your logic isn't this one then i **suggest you to edit the HTML** to fix this logic, which is the easiest way to do what you want.

---

**Second option:** I am assuming that you use a logic like this:

- `#li0` shows `#img0`
- `#li1` shows `#img1`
- `#li2` shows `#img2`
- ...
- `#liN` shows the Nth img of the array

Here's the code then:

```
function showOne() {
    var max = 4, // assuming that there are 5 images, from #img0 to #img4
        toShow = this.id.substr(2);


    $('#img'+toShow).show();
    for (var i=0; i < max; i++) {
        if (i != toShow) $('#img'+i).hide();
    }
}

$('#li0, #li1, #li2, #li3, #li4').bind('click', showOne);
```

In this snippet I only used 5 images, but you can add more images changing the `max` value and adding the relative `li` elements in the `$('#li0, #li1, ...)` selector.

Comment: This is extremely expensive and wasteful, and does not perform the change atomically, which can lead to significant desync of animations.  You could just make this a single atomic class change.  There's no reason to involve jQuery, binding, or dom walking.

Answer (score 1):

I see that your li's have ids of 'li1', 'li2', etc.  Assign them all a specific class, like 'liLinks'.

Then, add an event handler for that class like this:

```
$(".liLinks").click(function(){    
var ImageToShow = $(this).prop("id").replace("li", ""); // This gets the number of the li

    for (i=0; i<= 10; i++){ //or however many images you have
        if (i != ImageToShow)
            $("#img" + i).hide();
        else
            $("#img" + i).show();
    } 
});
```

Oh, and you can show and hide any other elements with the same method used above.  Just make sure their naming convention is the same, and you should be all set!

Answer (score 1):

Just hide all of them with CSS, then override the one you care about to show.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

      #showbox img { display: none; width: 300px; }

      #showbox.show1 img#img1,
      #showbox.show2 img#img2,
      #showbox.show3 img#img3,
      #showbox.show4 img#img4 { display: block; }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="showbox" class="3">
      <img id="img1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/ChessSet.jpg">
      <img id="img2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Chess_board_opening_staunton.jpg">
      <img id="img3" src="http://www.umbc.edu/studentlife/orgs/chess/images/News%20and%20Events/chess_sets.jpg">
      <img id="img4" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/Russisches_festungsschach.PNG/350px-Russisches_festungsschach.PNG">
    </div>

    <input onchange="document.getElementById('showbox').className = 'show' + this.value;">

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an approach:

1. Add special classes to identify images.
2. Use classes to show/hide image like: `.showing{display:block;}`
3. Use `data` attribute to store title like: `data-title="title"`
4. Add class to identify `li` and mark selected `li` with another class like `active`

```js
$(function() {
  $("li.switch").click(function() {
    var liActive = $("li.active");
    var imgActive = liActive.data("image");
    $(imgActive).removeClass("showing").addClass("hidden");
    $(liActive).removeClass("active");

    //currently clicked li
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass("active");
    var d = $this.data("image");
    $(d).removeClass("hidden").addClass("showing");
    $("#imgTitle").text($(d).data("title"));
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto auto;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.showing {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  list-style: none none outside;
  display: inline;
}
li {
  list-style: none none outside;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: #0f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery">
  <img src='https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3862/15320672416_65b28179b4_c.jpg' class='gimage showing' id='img1' data-title="This is image 1" />
  <img src='https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3893/15156335390_16e16aa1c9_c.jpg' class='gimage hidden' id='img2' data-title="This is image 2" />
  <img src='https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2942/15341799225_09d0f05098_c.jpg' class='gimage hidden' id='img3' data-title="This is image 3" />
  <img src='https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3907/15339877992_695dd1daae_c.jpg' class='gimage hidden' id='img4' data-title="This is image 4" />
  <img src='https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2942/15333547162_325fefd6d1.jpg' class='gimage hidden' id='img5' data-title="This is image 5" />
</div>
<div id="imgTitle"></div>
<ul>
  <li class="switch active" id="li1" data-image="#img1">1</li>
  <li class="switch" id="li1" data-image="#img2">2</li>
  <li class="switch" id="li1" data-image="#img3">3</li>
  <li class="switch" id="li1" data-image="#img4">4</li>
  <li class="switch" id="li1" data-image="#img5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Try it in this <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/eotmkpgh/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Your images is not hidden while the images is loading because you didn't use 
    $(function () {
        $("imgs").hide ();
    });
This function is excuted when the DOM (HTML) is loaded not the images.
The code will be "HTML":
     link1
     link2
     link3
    ...

jQuery:
    $(function () {
        $(".img").hide ();
        $(".nav").click (function (e) {
            $(".img").show ();
        });
    });

As you might expect you need to change this code to be more progressive but you now get the idea of making them hidden when the page finish liading not when the images finish downloading. And good luck ;) .

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $img = $('#images img'); /* Cache your selector */
$('#nav li').click(function(){
  $img.fadeOut().eq( $(this).index() ).stop().fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#images{ position:relative; }
#images img{ position:absolute; left:0; }
#images img + img {display:none; } /* hide all but first */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=nav>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<div id=images>
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/cf5" alt="">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/f0f" alt="">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/444" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix from  [Ricardo van den Broek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2348375/ricardo-van-den-broek)'s code, because

```
var imageId = $(this).data("imageId");
```

is seem doesn't work. It's returns "Undefined". So we need to change it to

```
var imageId = $(this).attr("data-imageId");
```

Here is all the code,

HTML (Thumbnail section)

```
<ul>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-imageId="0">
        Thumbnail 0
    </li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-imageId="1">
        Thumbnail 1
    </li>
    <li class="thumbnail" data-imageId="2">
        Thumbnail 2
    </li>
</ul>
```

HTML (Image section)

```
<div class="image" data-imageId="0">
    Image 0
</div>
<div class="image" data-imageId="1" style="display: none;">
    Image 1
</div>
<div class="image" data-imageId="2" style="display: none;">
    Image 2
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    $(".image").hide();

    // Shows the appropriate one.
    var imageId = $(this).attr("data-imageId");

    $(".image[data-imageId="+imageId+"]").show();
});
```