# Show element on hover and hide other elements

Tags: jquery

Below you see my html code. The divs are all hidden due to css rule to dropdown-menu class. When for example i hover on li with id 0 then to show div with id 0 etc.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="dropdown" id="0"><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="0">content 1</div>
<li class="dropdown" id="1"><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="1">content 2</div>
<li class="dropdown" id="2"><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="2">content 3</div>
</ul>
```

I have succeeded the above with the following code:

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function() {
     $(this).hover(function() {
         var myid=$(this).attr("id");
         $(this).parent().find("div#"+myid).show();
    });
});
```

but when i hover to the 3rd li then wherever i hover i see always the 3rd div. This is the one issue i don't know how to solve and second issue (supposing that the previous is solved) is that when i hover for example to first li and first div is shown then i need to be able to navigate to that div and not disappear immediately.

Any ideas are really appreciated!

Comment: you should never use same id for the elements. it should be unique. try something like: https://jsfiddle.net/13zn4xkk/

Comment: You should never have the same `ID` multiple times on a single page. You should be using either a `class` or `data` attribute

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027787/simplify-this-javascript-for-show-one-hide-rest

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use same ID multiple time in HTML page.
2. `div` inside `ul` tag also not valid HTML. So, put it inside `li` tag.

Try this way.

```js
$('ul.nav li').each(function() {
     $(this).hover(function() {
         var myid=$(this).attr("id");
         $(this).find("div").show();
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
<li class="dropdown" id="0"><a href="#">menu1</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">content 1</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">menu2</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">content 2</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown" id="2"><a href="#">menu3</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">content 3</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: With this solution when i hover out, the div shown is hidden again

Answer (score 0):

My bad, misread the question.

Try this:

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function() {
     $(this).mouseenter(function() {
         var myid=$(this).attr("id");
         $("#div"+myid).show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
          var myid=$(this).attr("id");
         $("#div"+myid).hide();
});
});
```

And change yout HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="dropdown" id="0"><a href="#">menu1</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="div0">content 1</div>
</li>

<li class="dropdown" id="1"><a href="#">menu2</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="div1">content 2</div>
</li>

<li class="dropdown" id="2"><a href="#">menu3</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="div2">content 3</div>
</li>

</ul>
```